# Upgrading to Composer 2 blocked by Symfony dependecies

Tags: 8, composer

I have an existing Drupal 8.9.16 site which uses Composer 1 (and Commerce 2.24). I am trying to upgrade to using Composer 2 using this guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/preparing-your-site-for-composer-2.

I have gotten through all the required steps up to the last step of dealing with drupal-scaffold (https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-drupals-composer-scaffold#s-migrating-composer-scaffold). The last step of that is to require drupal/core-recommended:^8.9. As I don't want to update core right now I am trying to run:

composer require drupal/core-recommended:8.9.16

but I am blocked by:

- Can only install one of: symfony/yaml[v3.4.41, v3.4.47].
- drupal/core-recommended 8.9.19 requires symfony/yaml v3.4.41 -> satisfiable by symfony/yaml[v3.4.41].

As a guess, I try requiring symfony/yaml:3.4.41. This fixes this issue and then moves on to the next symfony plugin which generates a similar error. Started going through all of these but there are a lot of symphony plugins and this can't possibly be the right way to do this.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried `composer require drupal/core-recommended:8.9.16 -w`? That will do any dependency updates along with the require. If you happen to be requiring any of the dependencies that are causing issues in your own composer.json, try the `-W` flag instead. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require for more info

Comment: There is no -w or -W option. BTW - i am doing this all still with Composer 1 as that is what the d.org guide states.

Comment: I didn't realise the alias wasn't available in Composer 1 - the option is though, use `--update-with-dependencies` instead

Comment: Same error. I suspect something is forcing 3.4.47 and since i can require 3.4.41; wonder if there isn't some way to replace all the symfony plugins at once?

Answer (score 2):

As is usually the fix, deleting the vendor folder and composer.lock file and then running:

- composer require drupal/core-recommended:8.9.16 --update-with-dependencies
  seems to have fixed the problem.

Since I deleted the .lock file it effectively runs a composer update which updated a few of the contrib modules. Not what i wanted; but I could have locked them in where they were if i was that worried about it. Core and Commerce were fixed to the version I was using so this remain untouched.

After that i was able to selfupdate to composer 2.x.